# How to use a variable of a IF Block statement in ELIF Block statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

While running this code i am getting error "Local variable "Files" referenced before assignment".
 I am thinking the scope of variable Files is limited to the IF block. Any suggestions?

```
import shutil
import os
import logging
import time
import re
timestr = '_'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")    
logging.basicConfig(filename = 
"//p4products//nemis2//filehandlerU//ENSUBAPP_log//ENSUBAPP.log"+timestr, level = logging.INFO, 
format = '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
src_dict = "//p4products/nemis2" 
pattern = re.compile ("Ena3s5npf_g") 

def Search_String_File(src_dict,pattern):
   for x in os.listdir(src_dict): 
    print(x)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src_dict, x)):
        files = os.path.join(src_dict,x)
        strng = open(files) 
        for lines in strng.readlines(): 
            try:
                if re.search(pattern, lines): 
                    print (re.split(r'=', lines))
            except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass
    elif x != "ENSUBAPP_search.py":
        return Search_String_File(files,pattern)

Search_String_File(src_dict,pattern)
```

Comment: Well, what should `files` be when `x != "ENSUBAPP_search.py"`??

Comment: Other directories or files. 
This is to prevent the code to search in itself code.

Comment: But you only defined `files` when `os.path.isfile`, so why would it be defined when that is not true? This problem is not specific to Python.

Comment: Ohh i got your point it should be swapped. My bad i was making changes in the code and never thought of this. 
Thanks for that correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking the scope of variable Files is limited to the IF block

That is correct, so move it to a different scope (the loop)

```
def search_string_file(src_dist, pattern):
    for x in os.listdir(src_dict): 
        print(x)
        child = os.path.join(src_dict,x)
        if os.path.isfile(child):
            with f as open(child):
                for line in f: 
                    try:
                        if re.search(pattern, line): 
                            print (re.split(r'=', line))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
        elif x != "ENSUBAPP_search.py":
            search_string_file(child, pattern)
```

Note: You may want to use `os.walk` or `os.glob` instead of `listdir`

Comment: Will try this one along with os.walk. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since ‘files’ is used in both cases (if/else), then you should define it outside of if.

Then you will also save one call to ‘join’ at the if statement.

Finally, you can use pathlib.Path and save your self some trouble and make a bit more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Search_String_File(src_dict,pattern):
   for x in os.listdir(src_dict): 
    print(x)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src_dict, x)):
        files = os.path.join(src_dict,x)
        strng = open(files) 
        for lines in strng.readlines(): 
            try:
                if re.search(pattern, lines): 
                    print (re.split(r'=', lines))
            except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass
    elif x != "ENSUBAPP_search.py":
        # declare the files value here, it seems like you should return from here,
        # i can't find any stopping point for this recursion function 
        return "pattern"
```

Comment: The recursion stopping point is finding a directory, or all `src_dist` files are scanned

Comment: I want the code to be like if the loop encounters a directory then it goes to else statement with new path and continue the search again
Thus using recursion.